# How can I change div's content when I'm clicking on another div whose content is generated from database

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, view, controller

I have next problem, I probably need to change div's content by clicking on another div, now I will explain it more detailed:

I am using MVC to build simple application which is about retreiving and sending messages, and now I am working on **Inbox view**, In my view I'm having loaded list of messages (which are retreived from my controller) for logged user, and right part of view is reserved to view a content of clicked message (which is located and listed in left part on my view as on image below), and this is how it looks (*ilustration not real image from my app, but same order of controls, content etc*):

[image]

As you can see guys, my view is separated into left and right part, on the left is list of messages for logged user, and on the right content of clicked message should be shown, I guess this must be done using javascript/ajax, but I almost had not experience in it, I don't know how can I on message click take message id or whatever, and by that filter right div's content (I guess that is the point).

Here is my view code:

```
    @model IEnumerable<MyApplication.Entities.Message>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div class="">
    <!-- /MAIL LIST (LEFT PART OF VIEW) -->
                <div class="x_content">

                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div class="mail_list">
                                        <div class="left">
                                            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="right">
                                            <h3>
                                                @item.Sender.Code @item.Sender.FirstName @item.Sender.LastName
                                                <small>@item.Created</small>
                                            </h3>
                                            <p>@item.Body</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            }
                        </div>

                        <!-- CONTENT MAIL -->
                        <div class="col-sm-9 mail_view">
                            <div class="inbox-body">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                                        <p class="date"> 23:32h 16.05.2017.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <h4>Subject</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="sender-info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <strong>User 1</strong>
                                            <span>(user11@gmail.com)</span> za
                                            <strong>user2</strong>
                                            <a class="sender-dropdown"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="view-mail">
                                    <p>Message content</p>

                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                        consequat.
                                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                                        eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
                                        sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button">
                                        <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
                                        Odgovori
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="button" data-placement="top"
                                            data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Forward">
                                        <i class="fa fa-share"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="button" data-placement="top"
                                            data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Print">
                                        <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="button" data-placement="top"
                                            data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Trash">
                                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- /CONTENT MAIL -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT - MY MODEL:

```
public class Message 
{
        #region Attributes

        public System.Guid MessageID { get; set; }

        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public bool UnRead { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public User Sender { get; set; }

        #endregion
}
```

Now I am wondering how could I filter/refresh/change content of this right part by clicking on left part ( loaded messages ).
Should I also include `MessageID` as `HiddenFor` in my loop to be able to get Id of selected message or whatever?

Anyway I really need help about this guys, even something to start with, some directions, whatever thanks a lot!
Cheers

Comment: simply create 2 views for right and left, and when view (div) on left click use ng-click to evalute function as true and use hg-show on the right to display right view

Comment: I think that we could just give you a flow to follow up. 
Set an element on the right view which holds the content of the message.
Retrieve the list of the messages and put them in the left view. Assign to them a unique identifier, using id or also a custom attribute. On these elements bind a click event starting an AJAX request to the server asking for the content of the message corresponding to that id. 
Once you get the response from the server, set the content of the right element equals to the message's content you got from the server.

Comment: @quirimmo I retrieved list of messages and throught for loop I displayed them in the left view. They allready have MessageID there so that is unique for each item on the left view, and maybe I don't need to make call to a server to get message informations because I 'm looping acctually message objects and there is all I need allready, I should just get it and display full message body/subject in the right part of view.. but I don't idea how can I do that.

Comment: use your MessageID as identifier of your elements on the left, bind a click event on those elements passing the current element and change the content of the view on the right assigning the corresponding body of the message you clicked. 
The structure of your objects is missing, your HTML is full of items. You could edit your post in order to show just the involved elements (so left items and right item for the view content) and the related code (structure of your messages) It would make it also easier to read

Comment: @quirimmo I made EDIT to simplify my HTML..

Comment: could you share your `Model` too please? I mean how a single item looks like

Comment: @quirimmo there it is :)

Comment: cool, writing few code for you and publishing it as reply on the answer, because I cannot paste code here easily

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144596/discussion-between-quirimmo-and-roxypro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for each item use a unique id which identifies the message and bind a function on click to it:

```
<a href="#" id="@item.MessageID" onclick="onSelectMessage(this);">
<!-- other stuffs here corresponding to the list -->
</a>
```

Then change your HTML of the view on the right in order to have an hook for the `p` which will hold the message's body. I am using an id because I assume that the view for reading messages content is unique and shown on the right:

```
<div class="view-mail">
  <p>Message content</p>
  <p id="email-body">
  </p>
</div>
```

Define your function in order to start an AJAX request to your controller and retrieve the body of the message corresponding to that ID:

```
function onSelectMessage(el) { 
  $.ajax({ 
    method: "GET", 
    url: "Message/GetMessageBody", 
    data: { messageID: el.id } 
  }) 
  .done(function( msg ) { 
    $('#email-body').text(msg); 
  }); 
}
```

Then setup your Controller in order to receive that AJAX request adding the following method:

```
[HttpPost] 
public string GetMessageBody(Guid messageID) 
{ 
  // retrieve the message corresponding to that id and return it
  // now returning an example string 
  return ("it worked the AJAX request for the message: " + messageID); 
}
```

Comment: on place where you put comment //here retrieve your item's body, corresponding to the el.id that acctually means I should call a controller's action method which will retrieve data from database by that el.id ?

Comment: you could do that, I was suggesting you to start an AJAX request and retrieve it. To me, it sounds better. But from your reply I understood that you already have client side also the bodies of your messages. 
Isn't it? 
Otherwise I will add a line of code for showing you how to start an AJAX request to your file too, and append the response to the body of the email when you have the response.
p.s. are you using jQuery too?

Comment: p.s. 2 if you already have client side in an array with all the objects, also the bodies of the messages, just retrieve the one corresponding to that id

Comment: how could I do that? whatever you post if is useful to me because I am absolutly begginer in this things such as javascript, jquery ajax etc :)

Comment: ok understood :) moved the discussion to a chat that there are few things to talk about, then I will change the answer after we will get something which suits your case

Comment: very professional and detailed answer! Thanks a lot.